# How to hide the id value into URL Or Parameter.

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am Fresher into Angular JS. I want to hide the parameter into  url when

I Click any anchor tag when I send any data to  another controller in

angular js.I don't  Want see any id and its value into url.

Link id as well as value into url?

Is It possible or not? Can We hide parameter or not.

Comment: Why? It can't be secret information or you wouldn't be sending it to the browser in the first place.

Comment: When you say you don't want to see "any id and its value into url", what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ui-router, which I highly recommend you do, you can have states with Non-url route parameters.

Non-URL route parameters:

> Another option that I discovered recently is how to pass parameters
>   that do not appear in the URL. This is particularly useful for
>   abstract states.

```
state('new-nonurl', {
  url: '/new',
  params: {
    portfolioId: null,
  },
  templateUrl: 'new.html',
  controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
     $scope.portfolioId = $stateParams.portfolioId;
  }
})
```

Here's the reference to the code and the quote
http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters